# How to add a page to a Next.js app through an external package?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page component which I need to add to an existing Next.js app through a custom package/module. Is there any way to add the page without putting it into /pages folder. Thanks!

Comment: you can use `custom routing` in next.js

Comment: In detail, you must add a file into the pages folder that imports your custom file, and custom routing can help to hit that endpoint and that way you can deal with it.

Comment: Thanks @NishargShah Do you mean dynamic routing? https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: @NishargShah The problem with your solution is that I still need to modify content of the /pages folder which already has other pages but I will definitely consider this option.

Comment: @KonstantinKomelin did you find any way to do that?

Comment: @Manish I didn't find a nice solution but I would look at Next.js Middleware https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware